# Move the "action nav-toggle" block into the "header.panel" on Magento 2

Tags: magento2, layout, luma-theme, hamburger-menu

I've done a **new magento 2 theme**, using same files from luma theme, with **blank parent theme**. Now what I'm trying to do, is to **move** the **`"action nav-toggle"`** element, basic the hamburger toggle icon on **mobile**, into the **`"header.panel"`** destination. What I can't do, is find the right name for the **`"action nav-toggle"`** so I can do the right code, I have already tried:

```
<move element="toggle.nav" destination="header.panel" before="-" />
<move element="toggle-nav" destination="header.panel" before="-" />
<move element="nav-toggle" destination="header.panel" before="-" />
<move element="nav.toggle" destination="header.panel" before="-" />
<move element="action.nav-toggle" destination="header.panel" before="-" />
<move element="action.nav.toggle" destination="header.panel" before="-" />
```

but non of them works, any idea what it might be?

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is kind of old but it showed up in some Google results when I was trying to do the same thing, so here is what I did to get this working.

In your custom theme, copy the logo.phtml file from Magento_Theme to:

> [Vendor]/[Theme]/Magento_Theme/templates/html/header/logo.phtml

Cut the .nav-toggle element out of that file and placed it into a new template file:

> [Vendor]/[Theme]/Magento_Theme/templates/nav-toggle.phtml

This new file should have just one line:
`<span data-action="toggle-nav" class="action nav-toggle"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Toggle Nav') ?></span></span>`

Now in your Magento_Theme layout file

> [Vendor]/[Theme]/Magento_Theme/etc/layout.xml

You can put the following:

`<referenceContainer name="header.panel">
   <block name="nav.toggle" before="-">
      <arguments>
          <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Theme::nav-toggle.phtml</argument>
      </arguments>
   </block>
</referenceContainer>`

Clear your caches, and your `pub/static/frontend/` and `var/view_preprocessed/` directories and you should be good to go.